# How to find a string in all tables and all columns?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to write a query to find a string wherever it exists.
Something that would work like:

```php
foreach(table in database) {
   foreach(column in table) {
      // in the end, i need to know, which columns in
      // which tables that string appears.
   }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Can you give us the reasoning behind your current requirement?

Comment: In any case, I'm interested in a solution to *this* problem - I could definitely use it. *My* reason is to update URLs from the IP address in an entire site after it goes live (this is a utility in the control panel), currently I have a system that registers tables/columns for the search, but this would be easier.

Comment: thanks, Jam, but this is exactly what i need. I picked up an infinitely big and messy database, and need to know where some values are.

Comment: Is [this](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/search-through-all-databases-tables-columns-in-) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why? Honestly, unless it is something you need to do at runtime, I would use `mysqldump` and use a text editor to do the search.

If you have to do this at runtime, you are going to have to build something dynamically. You can use "`show tables`" to get a list of tables. You can then use `show columns` for each of those tables. You'd then need to do some sort of select statement on each column looking for your text (using locate, or using like for example).

This is going to be a really slow process to run at real-time on a server...

Comment: thanks, the dump solution will probably work for me, as it's something to do statically, not at runtime, though i would really love to know the most elegant hipothesis, to do it directly through mySQL

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible. But I don't think you can do it in pure SQL; you'd better do it in  some script languages, like PHP, or shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I dare to say, this is impossible with (current) MySQL, as metadata (such as column names) and data (such as the field values) cannot be part of the same query.

Especially

```
SELECT Field from (DESCRIBE <tablename>)
```

will error out, as will

```
SELECT Field from (SHOW FIELDS FROM <tablename>)
```

as will

```
DECLARE flds CURSOR FOR DESCRIBE <tablename>
```

in a stored procedure.

This is to say it is impossible INSIDE MYSQL - it is trivial in PHP and freinds.